# How to install Mozilla's implementation of Baidu deep speech on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, speech-recognition, baidu, mozilla-deepspeech

I'm on Windows 10, and when I try to install [Mozilla's implementation of 
 Baidu Deep speech](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech) as shown [here](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech).

Using:

```
pip install deepspeech
```

I get this error : "*Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement deepspeech (from versions:)
No matching distribution found for deepspeech*"

Is there another way to install it on windows?

Comment: this project probably [don't support windows](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/issues/632), but you could try to install from source.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and let you know.

Answer (score 4):

**Hi, after a little research, I found a way to get DeepSpeech run on Windows, but using a Ubuntu back-end.**

Here is the link of the blog where you'll find all the detailed steps about how to make DeepSpeech work on Windows, enjoy : https://fotidim.com/deepspeech-on-windows-wsl-287cb27557d4